# Preventing Android Keyboard from pushing layout

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I created a form using bootstrap, css, and html.

However when I click on the text area on an android phone(that is, when it comes into focus), the bottom half of the textarea changes color.

I don't understand why its turning white.
By the way: It works fine on a PC.

[image: Normal]
[image: Bottom half is white]

My css Code:

```
    .container-fluid{
       background-color: #EF4247;
     border-color: #EF4247;
     }
form {
            height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 50;
           background-color: #EF4247;
     border-color: #EF4247;
    text-align: center;

    margin: 0;
    }


h1{
text-align:center;
}

textarea{ width:200px;
}

.form-horizontal .control-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

My HTML code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


     </head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>SEND ME SOME MAIL</h1>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="mail.php" method="post" >
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="subject">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textarea">Text Area</label>
  <div class="controls">                     
    <textarea id="textarea"  rows="10" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message here:"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>

</form>


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fitter-happier-text.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you put the background colour on the body instead of the form? If so then it could be a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the underlying issue in this particular example is that the behaviour of the bootstrap `container-fluid` CSS style appears to be incompatible with your desired effect on mobile devices.

My answer to this is merely encapsulate your form with a new block element and set your background on that. Then set `min-height:100%` on this new block container, as well as the `<html>` and `<body>` elements.

Something like this:

```
html, body {
  min-height:100%;height:100%;
}
.red-background-not-on-body-or-html {
  background-color: #EF4247;    
  min-height:100%;
}
```

And html like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="red-background-not-on-body-or-html">
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- FORM HERE -->
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

As far as your example goes, you could also just put the `background-color` attribute on the `<body>` or `<html>` tags themselves.

Otherwise, if you still require that the background respect the `.container-fluid` CSS logic, then you could try a hack with media queries for handheld devices but it could get messy.

You could also try re-ordering so that the form is outside the fluid logic then add `min-height:100%` to the form.

[**JSBin to illustrate**](http://jsbin.com/rosanobura)

Comment: Doing that makes the web page look funny on a PC.
http://prasanthlouis.com/index1.html

However the issue is fixed when using an android phone.

Comment: Edited my answer with added width/height attributes. I *think* this will still be ok on mobile; but haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old post, but anyway here what you can do.

```
body {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I delay the focus:

```
// If the form has the focus the keyboard moves the layout
setTimeout(() => this.focus(0), 1000);
```